# Misplaced a copy of I-94

Tags: legal, lost-documents, fraud

I misplaced a print of my I-94 form which contains my passport number, date of birth and legal name.

What harm, if any can be done using this information?

I am primarily worried about the passport number since name, DOB (although harmful) are not very hard to obtain otherwise as well.

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but essentially the same question: [What damage can person/s do if they have your passport number and visa control number?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/69473/19400).